# Adding bulk posts with wp_insert_post() getting internal server error

Tags: php, wordpress

I have written a bulk import script where I import posts with the `wp_insert_post()` function using taxonomy names. Basically there are 4000 cities, and I want to add them as posts such as:

- New York to London
- New York to Amsterdam
- New York to Berlin

etc...

But I'm getting an internal server error after adding a few thousand posts. I expect the total posts added to be 16,000,000‬ [4,000 * 4,000]

Here is the code:

```
<?php
require_once "wp-load.php";
ini_set("memory_limit",-1);
set_time_limit(0);
ignore_user_abort(true);

$term_query = new WP_Term_Query( array( 'taxonomy' => 'cities' ) );
if ( ! empty( $term_query->terms ) ) {
    wp_defer_term_counting( true );
    define( 'WP_IMPORTING', true );
    foreach ( $term_query ->terms as $term ) {
    $city1 = $term->name;
        foreach ( $term_query ->terms as $inner_city ) {
            $city2 = $inner_city->name;
            $postTitle = $city1 . ' to ' . $city2;
            $postSlug  = $city1 . '-to-' . $city2;
            $LowerPostSlug = strtolower($postSlug);
            $post_args = array(
                'post_title' => $postTitle,
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'post_name' => $postSlug,
                'post_author' => $user_ID,
                'post_type' => 'conversion',
            );
        $found_post_title = get_page_by_title( $postTitle, OBJECT, 'city_post' );
        $found_post_id = $found_post_title->ID;

        if ( FALSE === get_post_status( $found_post_id ) ):
            $returned_post_id = wp_insert_post( $post_args );
            update_field( 'city_1', $city1, $returned_post_id ); # SET CUSTOM FIELD FOR city 1
            update_field( 'city_2', $city2, $returned_post_id ); # SET CUSTOM FIELD FOR city 2
            echo $postTitle . '</br>';
        endif;
        }
    }
    wp_defer_term_counting( false );
}
```

Comment: Whats on your logs? It seems you run out of memory or timeout while processing this thousands of inserts

Comment: Is the `$user_ID` variable initialized? If the `post_author` column is required, then you have to pass proper value for it.

Comment: @Raffobaffo this is the only error: `PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'ID' of non-object in /app/public/get-cities.php on line 27`